# Unable to Connect to Public IP From Terminal

Tags: networking, proxy

I am trying to connect to a public GKE cluster from my terminal and the connection just times out.

```
telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 443
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

What is really strange is that I can access the IP from my firefox browser.

I am behind a corporate cntlm proxy but I cannot see why it wouldn't work for the terminal while it works fro the browser. My browser is vanilla and not managed by my corporation.

My env looks fine:

```
$ env | grep -i prox
                                                                                        
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
rsync_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com,alexander-vmware,*collaboration.com,localhost,127.0.0.1
ftp_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

My firefox settings:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I am behind a corporate cntlm proxy but I cannot see why it wouldn't work for the terminal while it works fro the browser.

Those proxies are used mostly by HTTP clients only. (It's not automatic; each and every program that uses proxies has to support them separately.) Telnet is *not* an HTTP client, so it doesn't know that it should use a proxy; very few non-HTTP tools have proxy support built in.

You would need to tell it to connect *to the proxy*, then issue the proxy `CONNECT` command manually:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 3128 ↵
CONNECT xx.xx.xx.xx:443 HTTP/1.0 ↵
↵
```

...or use the `proxytunel` tool to handle this.

```
$ proxytunnel -p 127.0.0.1:3128 -d xx.xx.xx.xx:443
```

(proxytunnel can even talk NTLM directly to the real proxy if you use the `-N` or `--ntlm` option. It doesn't support Kerberos, but then neither does cntlm.)

Comment: Hello thank you for the explanations would you also know why when I do: "proxytunnel -v -d google.com:443 -a 9999" and then curl localhost:9999 I get "Self-referential requests to proxy are forbidden" ?

Comment: Because you're asking it to access the domain `localhost`.